# Issue with Restoring tensorflow graph

Tags: python, tensorflow

i build a neural net with tensorflow, and i saved it after training, but when a i want to restore it in order to make a prediction, it doesn't work that's what i get:

```
 2017-09-10 22:51:58.530272: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-
 win\m\windows\py\36\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: 
 Key Variable_10 not found in checkpoint

 Key Variable_10 not found in checkpoint
```

i don't know where is the issue, here's where i save the file:

```
   model_file = "C:/Users/ben-n_000/Desktop/travail 
   signal_courant/signal_courant_new/TensorFlow_model/model.ckpt"
```

i saved the model properly

```
   saver = tf.train.Saver()
   saver.save(sess, model_file)
```

and here comes the issue :

```
    with tf.Session() as sess:
         sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

         saver = tf.train.Saver()
         saver.restore(sess, model_file)
```

It's quite frustrating, i can't understand what's the issue, so i need your help, thnaks.

Comment: What error do you see? I don't understand how to answer this question.

Comment: it say's that the key variables are not found in checkpoint

Comment: Can you put a full stack trace? Can you check whether the files are empty? Have you used the inspect_checkpoint tool to check whether the saving is happening?

Comment: Thanks @AlexandrePassos for your answers, when i save the model, the files are created (checkpoints , model.cptk.data-00000-of-00001, model.cptk.index and model.cptk.meta)

Comment: @AlexandrePassos I just used the inspect_checkpoint.py and it works, i find all the variables, so when the error says for exempl :variable_10 not found in checkpoint, it don't make a sens since i found it in the checkpoint inspection

Comment: In fact i was wrong, it's the vars from (20 to 30) which are missing in checkpoint according to the error, and when i look for thme with the checkpoint incpection tool, i don't find them, so what's the problem?

Comment: So it looks like those variables are somehow not being saved. Are you instantiating the saver after all the variables are created?

Comment: @AlexandrePassos, I managed to solve the issue by doing the followinf steps: in my code i have a train function and a make _prediction function, the first saver.save i was doing it after innitializing all variables that's the first issue, the second is in the restore step, i put the saver.save in the function make_prediction, so i put it outside and before the calle of make prediction i will answer my question with the code thnaks Alexandre Passos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have 2 functions train_network and make_prediction, for saving the model and reusing it in the make_prediction function that's how it works

```
     def train_neural_network(x):
       '''
       code here 
       ''' 
       #saver before innitalizing alla variables
       saver = tf.train.Saver()
       with tf.Session() as sess:
          sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
          '''
          code here 
          '''


     def make_prediction(Z):
       '''
       code here 
       '''
       with tf.Session() as sess:
          sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
          saver.restore(sess, model_file)
          '''
          code here 
          '''
```

and here at the end of the code we can call our functions and put the saver before the calling of make_prediction :

```
      train_neural_network(x)
      saver = tf.train.Saver()
      make_prediction(X_test[1])
```